# How to change label's style when I change radio inputs?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, radio-button, label, styled-components

I created the className "OccupancyChecked" so it would be applied to the label of the radio that is checked, but for some reason I can't make it work.

This is the style:

```js
const Occupancy = styled.label`
  //more code

  .OccupancyChecked {
    border: 1px solid rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.24);
    background: #7f5cf1;
  }
`;
```

The following is the code calling the above's className. What I tried to do was: There are just two radios, so I inserted a `onChange` on the first radio, the result is in each label's className, where it should call `"Occupancy"` className in case radio is `checked` or blank className if otherwise. I believe this logic should work, but it isn't. I also created a [sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/unruffled-williamson-dj72y?file=/src/App.tsx) so I can display the code running.

```js
export default function App() {
  const [occupancyChecked, setOccupancyChecked] = useState(0);

  function changeOccupancyChecked() {
    occupancyChecked === 0 ? setOccupancyChecked(1) : setOccupancyChecked(0);
    return;
  }

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <Occupancy>
        <label
          htmlFor="radioTeacher"
          className={occupancyChecked === 0 ? "OccupancyChecked" : ""}
        >
          <input
            type="radio"
            name="occupancy"
            id="radioTeacher"
            onChange={changeOccupancyChecked}
            checked
          />
          <span>I'm a teacher</span>
        </label>
        <label
          htmlFor="radioStudant"
          className={occupancyChecked === 1 ? "OccupancyChecked" : ""}
        >
          <input type="radio" name="occupancy" id="radioStudant" />
          <span>I'm a studant</span>
        </label>
      </Occupancy>
    </div>
  );
}
```

How can this be fixed? display the className `OccupancyChecked` in the checked radio.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the default `checked` in radioTeacher is the main cause. I have updated it for better understanding.

[Working link](https://codesandbox.io/s/prakash-checkbox-color-rt1id)

```js
import "./styles.css";
import styled from "styled-components";
import { useEffect, useState } from "react";

const Occupancy = styled.label`
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  margin-bottom: 1rem;
  font-size: 0.7rem;
  font-family: "Open Sans", sans-serif;
  font-weight: 400;

  label {
    border: 1px solid #6f49ed;
    background: #6f49ed;
    border-radius: 4px;
    padding: 1rem;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    width: 48%;

    input {
    }

    span {
      margin-left: 0.4rem;
    }
  }
  .OccupancyChecked {
    border: 1px solid rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.24);
    background: red;
  }
`;

export default function App() {
  const [occupancyChecked, setOccupancyChecked] = useState(0);

  const changeOccupancyChecked = (val) => {
    console.log("Value to set:", val);
    setOccupancyChecked(val);
    //occupancyChecked === 0 ? setOccupancyChecked(1) : setOccupancyChecked(0);
    //return;
  };

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <Occupancy>
        <label
          htmlFor="radioTeacher"
          className={occupancyChecked === 0 ? "OccupancyChecked" : ""}
        >
          <input
            type="radio"
            name="occupancy"
            id="radioTeacher"
            onChange={() => {
              changeOccupancyChecked(0);
            }}
          />
          <span>I'm a teacher</span>
        </label>
        <label
          htmlFor="radioStudant"
          className={occupancyChecked === 1 ? "OccupancyChecked" : ""}
        >
          <input
            type="radio"
            name="occupancy"
            id="radioStudant"
            onChange={() => {
              changeOccupancyChecked(1);
            }}
          />
          <span>I'm a studant</span>
        </label>
      </Occupancy>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: There is only one problem with this code, none of the inputs starts as ```checked```, that was something that happened in the original code

Comment: I have updated the example to add  checked={occupancyChecked === 0} and             checked={occupancyChecked === 1}
 so it will start with selection accordingly. @MestreALMO